# Transformaing CURL post request to python request

Tags: python, curl

I am running a CURL command and want to update it to python request command.
CURL Command:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -k -s --date '{"command": "/semate:severitytoAll', "target": "/gen1/gateway[(@name=\"@gname\")]/directory/probe[(@name=\"@probn\")]/managedE[(@name=\"@me\")]/sam[@name=\"PRO")] [(@type=\"\')]/dav[(@name=\"PRO\")]/row/rows[(@name=\""PRO_D\')]", "args': {"1": "testing sn via Rest aPI", '2": 1, "4":3}}' -u @gatName
```

Can someone guide me with the equivalent python request commands please
Regards
Bicky

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions

Comment: Also your content is not valid at all, that not a JSON content, and not a valid string for a bash terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check https://www.postman.com/product/rest-client/
Write it in Postman, select code and select Python.

Comment: I am unable to identify where to write it out. Could you help me with the command.

Comment: https://monosnap.com/file/KkBwGJF1DFmod4UTnMZINwUIe686qL
https://monosnap.com/file/fM4enz9yHbE5BuQgMYngXJIxHOx3Jn
https://monosnap.com/file/LGqtZsEVvAphr4GhGHu2m96MJl5avN